# ADHoc Information Retrieval

Tags: tesseract, information-retrieval, data-extraction, python-tesseract

I want to extract the total bill from image receipts. I could extract the entire data present in the image but now I am struck with the problem of extracting only the information that I need.

This is the image that I have.

[image]

I am pasting the extracted information from the image

```
m cm lnnk 3mm: :33; no 1 z m
x Visut all! ms“; (or nulnunn mfn an an: nan.



Sub Iota] 19.56
TOTAL 19.56
VISA 1956
Fun 19.56
D!!! You Know 0



For ureat-tastlru dessens under 200
cahries, try our Triple Berry Frozen
Yogurt Sunda: a dish of Frozen Yogurt.
or a Vanma rozen Vugurt Done.
```

From this data I just want to extract the total bill. To get this I found out that I could use Ad Hoc Normalization (Adhoc retrieval). Can someone provide any insights on Adhoc retrieval. If there are any other option to extract the data from the image please let me do so. I am using tesseract to extract this information. Sometimes it is no giving the proper output. I could use some help in improvising the output given by the tesseract.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information? Is the desired output "19.56"? Does this need to run on multiple bills?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need ad hoc retrieval in this case? Since you are getting the OCR result from the receipt, you can simply perform a regular text search for the item appearing next to "TOTAL".

There are algorithms for image text search, but this seems like overkill for such a straightforward application unless there is a good reason to do so.